# Form_for two referenced models error - Ruby on Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created 2 models (User, UserInformation) and created a form with FormHelper and fields_for. I followed this guide Railscast #196-nested-model-form-part-1 to make it work, but it doesn't. I just want to have one form that creates a user that can have only one UserInformation row, and I want the UserInformation to belong to only one User.

### Error

[This is a screenshot of the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQU7I.png)

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :userinformation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :userinformation
end
```

#### app/models/user_information.rb

```
class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### app/views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <% f.fields_for :userinformation do |builder| %>
  <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :birthdate %><br>
      <%= builder.date_field :birthdate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :address %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :city %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :country %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :country %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.userinformation.build
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email)
    end
end
```

#### db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160531152010) do

  create_table "user_informations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "country"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "user_informations", ["user_id"], name: "index_user_informations_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code looks correct, but make sure you've allowed the user information params.

Example:

```
permitted = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

[Params ddoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

However, if we take a step back, I'd be interested to know if you have a valid reason to split user and user information. From a logical standpoint, having **a one-to-one relationship does not make sense**. So, if I were you, I'd probably merge those two tables together.

Usually a good database design simplify the development. :)

**EDIT**

Regarding the chat discussion:

[image: E/R schema]

[Rails STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

Comment: I've merged the tables, but i would like to have "normal user" (with the merged tables data) and a table where i could store "business user" data like "company number", "vat number" etc. What is the best solution?

Comment: If I understand your domain correctly, I think the "normal user" and the "business user" you are referring to are the same entity. Therefore I'd merge them together. Can a normal user exist without a business user or vice-versa? If we have a strict 1:1 relationship (not 1:0-1), it is the same entity. What are your motivations behind this split?

Comment: My project(university) is about a banking account system where an User can have a "Personal" type account and a "Business" type account. I thougth the right way is to create an User model(with info) and a table for business information. What do you think?

Comment: I see, but can a user have multiple accounts?

Comment: Yes, like i have a bank account and i can open subaccount on the same ID

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Here is how I'd design your data model. It is based on my understanding of the problem, so I decline any responsibility for bad grades. :)

Comment: Ok i think this is a better design. No bad grades! thanks

Comment: Ehi, because i don't want to create another question,i would ask there. I've created the `user` table and the `account` table but i have a problem. I've created a form for the creation of the user, i've added the `fields_for` the `account` table in the same form, but i'm unable to create the user and account of his choice in the same time.. Can you explain me, or give me some resource, to better understand how association works pratically? i know about the has_many, belongs_to ecc but i'm unable to pratically use these. Please explain to me..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is change `:userinformation` to `:user_information` in your `User` model as well as the controller and views - when converting `CamelCase` to `snake_case`, the underscore takes the place of the capital letter. Apart from that I think it all looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your User controller

```
def new
 @user = User.new
 @user.build_userinformation
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, userinformation_attributes: [:birthdate, :address, :city, :country ])
end
```